# D3 Real-Time streamgraph (Graph Data Visualization)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, real-time, transition, stream-graph

I would like a stream graph as in this example:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stream.html

[image]

but I would like real time data entering from the right and have old data leave from the left, such that I always have a window of 200 samples. How would I do this such that I have the appropriate transitions?

I tried changing the data points in the array a and then recreating an area as such

```
  data0 = d3.layout.stack()(a);
```

but my transitions do not make it look like the chart is sliding across the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/):

> When implementing realtime displays of time-series data, we often use the x-axis to encode time as position: as time progresses, new data comes in from the right, and old data slides out to the left. If you use D3’s built-in [path interpolators](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions), however, you may see some surprising behavior...
>
> To eliminate the wiggle, **interpolate the transform rather than the path**. This makes sense if you think of the chart as visualizing a function—its value isn’t changing, we’re just showing a different part of the domain. By sliding the visible window at the same rate that new data arrives, we can seamlessly display realtime data...

Comment: Thanks! I ran through the tutorial, but I had a lot of trouble trying to extrapolate that to the stream graph example.

I finally used this line of code to shift my multiple paths over.

vis.selectAll("path").data(data0).attr("d", area).attr("transform", null).transition().duration(50).ease("linear").attr("transform", "translate(" + -10 + ")").each("end", function (d,i) { if (i==0) transition();});

I can only recursively call transition on the first path, otherwise the entire graph shifts once for everypath, and then I have an explosion of callbacks. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I've posted my example here:
http://lyngbaek.com/real-time-stream-graph.html
every so often the bottom 'path' gets misaligned from the 'top' one, probably by the way I do my recursive transition() call.

I extrapolated from your tutorial and created a separate data array for the top and bottom paths. Then I individual push a new value to each of them. I have to then recompute a new d3.layout.stack() and redraw it. I then shift my 2 data arrays and repeat.

Is this the correct methodology, or is there a cleaner way to do it.

Thanks again!

Comment: That's most of what I was looking for with my question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764813/producing-a-live-graph-with-d3

How do you recommend getting the data from the server to the client?

Comment: i already write waves in http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/DAShs/1/..But how to create like this in D3js.Can you please give me sample

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/237685) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hello, is there anyway to do this in a Java desktop aplication ?

Comment: If you translate infinitely wont you run into large numbers and run out of memory?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cqDA9/1/
It shows a possible solution to keeping track and updating the different data series.

```
var update = function () {
    for (Name in chart.chartSeries) {
        chart.chartSeries[Name] = Math.random() * 10;
    }
    for (Name in chart2.chartSeries) {
        chart2.chartSeries[Name] = Math.random() * 10;
    }
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
}
setTimeout(update, 1000);
```