# how to make real time multi line chart using d3 while getting data from Json?

Tags: json, d3.js, linechart

I am new to `D3` ,i want to make a multi line chart using d3.js while getting data from a json object can anyone guide me.here is working sample code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .graph .axis {
        stroke-width: 1;
    }

    .graph .axis .tick line {
        stroke: black;
    }

    .graph .axis .tick text {
        fill: black;
        font-size: 0.7em;
    }

    .graph .axis .domain {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
    }

    .graph .group {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="graph"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var limit = 60 * 1,
        duration = 750,
        now = new Date(Date.now() - duration)

    var width = 500,
        height = 200

    var groups = {
        current: {
            value: 0,
            color: 'orange',
            data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                return 0
            })
        },
        target: {
            value: 0,
            color: 'green',
            data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                return 0
            })
        },
        output: {
            value: 0,
            color: 'grey',
            data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                return 0
            })
        }
    }

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([now - (limit - 2), now - duration])
        .range([0, width])

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([height, 0])

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('basis')
        .x(function(d, i) {
            return x(now - (limit - 1 - i) * duration)
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d)
        })

    var svg = d3.select('.graph').append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height + 50)

    var axis = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'))

    var paths = svg.append('g')

    for (var name in groups) {
        var group = groups[name]
        group.path = paths.append('path')
            .data([group.data])
            .attr('class', name + ' group')
            .style('stroke', group.color)
    }

    function tick() {
    now = new Date()

        // Add new values
        for (var name in groups) {
            var group = groups[name]
            //group.data.push(group.value) // Real values arrive at irregular intervals
            group.data.push(20 + Math.random() * 100)
            group.path.attr('d', line)
        }

        // Shift domain
        x.domain([now - (limit - 2) * duration, now - duration])

        // Slide x-axis left
        axis.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .call(x.axis)

        // Slide paths left
        paths.attr('transform', null)
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration) + ')')
            .each('end', tick)

        // Remove oldest data point from each group
        for (var name in groups) {
            var group = groups[name]
            group.data.shift()
        }
    }

    tick()
    </script>
</body>
```

but i need straight line running line chart with bum on some point depending on values so here is image of chart i wanted any help will be greatly appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Sorry @Hassan - I don't see how `Angular.js` fits into the question? Is it part of the question or is this just a pure `D3.js` question?

Comment: @Ian ignore angularjs its pure d3.js question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [producing a "live" graph with D3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764813/producing-a-live-graph-with-d3)

Comment: @Ian but i needed multi line not single getting data from json

Comment: The approach is the same though - so use that approach and apply it over multiple series. If you have a specific problem with applying that approach then feel free to ask another question, but for me personally to answer this I'd literally be taking that code and modifying it till I'd implemented the chart you're after. It'd be better for you to go through that process and learn how `D3` works properly