# Add new data to d3js area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, real-time, d3fc

I used this tutorial to display an yahoo chart with d3js http://bl.ocks.org/ColinEberhardt/c806028e47281b8dbb1d
now i would like to make it as Real Time chart,and i would like some help to add data every 10 seconds for example. 
Thanks

PS : I am using d3js and d3fc, and i don't use path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [producing a "live" graph with D3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764813/producing-a-live-graph-with-d3)

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/ColinEberhardt/c806028e47281b8dbb1d

Comment: There is an example of a 'live' chart rendered with d3fc here https://d3fc.io/examples/streaming/index.html - you simply add / remove data points and re-render the chart.