# Smooth update to x axis in a D3 line chart?

Tags: animation, graph, d3.js, line, transition

I have an example animated line chart located here: http://www.animatedcreations.net/d3/animatedLineChart.html

Everything is working as I would like it to, except that the redraw on the graph line is not smooth as in the example at the bottom of this page: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/.  Another problem is that the line and x axis are slightly out of sync.

I am pretty sure the problem with code lies in how .attr("d", line) is updated.  Any help would be very much appreciated - I've been stuck for a while!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on StackOverflow! First of all, please know for next question that creating a jsFiddle (or similar) can be quite useful for users who want to help you in this kind of problem as playing with the code is often necessary. I created a jsFiddle with exactly your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/peDzT/

I have spent quite a bit of time figuring out what was happening in your source code. Here are a few remarks:

- You have two nested svgs
- In `tick()`, when you use `path.attr("transform","null")` it does nothing. Instead you have to do `path.select(".line").attr("transform", "null").
- In the other `attr.transform()` call, you forgot to call `x()` on the argument.

Final result: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/YruDh/

In order to achieve this result I got inspired by another example I made previously, which is quoted in the following (related btw) question: [Real time line graph with nvd3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330390/real-time-line-graph-with-nvd3-js)

Comment: uao. This question solves my problem of out-of-sync axis and plot ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/25125534/433685 ) - even if I don't understand why - but I don't manage to replace `t` in your example with `new Date()` to make a time-labeled axis. Any hint?

Comment: also in the example you posted in the related question ( http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/buRcx/1/ ) if you put the `duration` at a small value (like 50) there is the out-of-sync problem: the axis is much more faster then the plot!

Comment: @ChristopherChiche - awesome thread here.  I'm trying to figure out how to update the Y axis (scale) so that it adjusts to accommodate higher values.  Can you show an example (js fiddle fork) of how I can accomplish that?

Comment: @tamak Thanks! I think the easiest would be to open another question for this specific issue with a minimal example of your issue.