# Time series line chart is not sync with axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series

This experiment is based on [this d3 official example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/). What I'm trying to achieve is to visualise the last x minutes of a time series data. I have a copy of the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/225dC/3/). Click to add a new data.

The problem is that the chart is not in sync with the axis. Both the chart and the axis is translating by the same transition.

Maybe I'm in the wrong way and what I'm trying to achieve can be done in some easiest way. Please help.

In the end the jsfiddle code.

html:

```
<h1>Click to plot</h1>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

js:

```
var n = 200,
    duration = 150,
    count = 0,
    data = d3.range(n).map(function() { return 0; });

// canvas size
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 400,
    height = 200;

// input data model
var x = d3.time.scale();
var y = d3.scale.linear();
updateDomains(new Date() - duration);

var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

// axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(6);

var xAxisG = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate("+(margin.left)+"," + (height) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// the line chart
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(new Date() - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

var path = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate("+(margin.left)+",0)")
    .attr("class", "path")
    .append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line");

tick();

d3.select(window)
    .on("click", function() { ++count; });

function tick() {

  // update the domains
  updateDomains(new Date());

  // push the accumulated count onto the back, and reset the count
  data.push(Math.min(30, count));
  count = 0;

  redrawLine();

  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();
}

function redrawLine() {
  // redraw the line
  svgContainer.select(".line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null);

  // slide the x-axis left
  xAxisG.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .ease("linear")
      .call(xAxis);

  // slide the line left
  path.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", 
            "translate(" + x(new Date() - (n - 1) * duration) + ")")
      .each("end", tick);
}

function updateDomains(now) {
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
    x.range([0, width]);

    y.range([height, 0]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data)]);
}
```

css:

```
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

#chart {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}


.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have better luck using a common scale for the x axis and the data, it's what intended to be used for stuff like this.

Comment: sorry can you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

Actually in your code, I see you are using new Date() which changes when the function is executing. so your scale for axis and scale for drawing elements gets changed.
Can you try replaceing below line

```
updateDomains(new Date() - duration);
```

with

```
var currentDate = new Date();
updateDomains(currentDate - duration);
```

Also in tick function send currentDate to displayDomains function.
when you want to change the scale you change variable currentDate.

Hope it helps.

Ganesh