# Updating Nvd3 chart priodically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I'm working with Nvd3 charts from the examples from their official website. Now I want a line chart to update periodically based on data sent from server but I couldn't found any useful Example for this on internet.

I have created a function which re-draws the chart when new data is arrived but i want to append every new point to the existing chart (like we can do in highcharts) but i'm stuck. 
Here is the code I'm using for Updating the chart.

```
var data = [{
    "key" : "Long",
    "values" : getData()
}];
var chart;

function redraw() {

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart().margin({
            left : 100
        })
        //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true) //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
        .transitionDuration(350) //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
        .showLegend(true) //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
        .showYAxis(true) //Show the y-axis
        .showXAxis(true);

        //Show the x-axis
        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
        });

        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

        d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data)
        //.transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    });
}

function getData() {
    var arr = [];
    var theDate = new Date(2012, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (var x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
        arr.push({
            x : new Date(theDate.getTime()),
            y : Math.random() * 100
        });
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

setInterval(function() {
    var long = data[0].values;
    var next = new Date(long[long.length - 1].x);
    next.setDate(next.getDate() + 1)
    long.shift();
    long.push({
        x : next.getTime(),
        y : Math.random() * 100
    });
    redraw();
}, 1500);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NVD3 - How to refresh the data function to product new data on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689157/nvd3-how-to-refresh-the-data-function-to-product-new-data-on-click)

Comment: This is not em asking brother. I'm looking to append data to the existing chart , not redrawing chart with the new data. The code I pasted is already doing it. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Well, in your code you're **re-drawing your entire chart** at every interval. And if you have a close look at my code, I've made `chartData` to contain the SVG selection and its data. So if you ever want to update the data, that's what you will have to call like in my `update()` function to update the chart data. Its a more efficient way of updating the chart. Just have a look at your browser console, it will be printing the NVD3 load time during every interval :|

Comment: I'm assuming your looking for something like a real time chart update, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330390/real-time-line-graph-with-nvd3-js)